# Conditional operator in Transact-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to do this shorter, for instance using some sort of conditional operator in Transact-sql?

```
IF @ParentBinaryAssetStructureId = -1
BEGIN
    SET @ParentBinaryAssetStructureId = NULL
END

UPDATE  BinaryAssets.BinaryAssetStructures 
SET     ParentBinaryAssetStructureId = @ParentBinaryAssetStructureId
WHERE   BinaryAssetStructureId = @OriginalBinaryAssetStructureId
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

USE [NULLIF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

```
UPDATE  BinaryAssets.BinaryAssetStructures 
SET     ParentBinaryAssetStructureId = NULLIF(@ParentBinaryAssetStructureId,-1)
WHERE   BinaryAssetStructureId = @OriginalBinaryAssetStructureId
```

Answer (score 4):

The ternary (conditional) operator in c like languages:

```
x = doSomething ? 5 : 7
```

would be written like this in SQL:

```
SELECT @x = CASE WHEN @doSomething = 1 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END
```

There can be multiple cases (when clauses):

```
SELECT @x = CASE WHEN @doSomething = 1 THEN 5 WHEN @somethingElse = 1 THEN 20 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE  BinaryAssets.BinaryAssetStructures 
SET     ParentBinaryAssetStructureId =
   CASE  ParentBinaryAssetStructureId  
     WHEN -1 THEN NULL
     ELSE ParentBinaryAssetStructureId
   END
WHERE   BinaryAssetStructureId = @OriginalBinaryAssetStructureId
```

Give that a whirl